# Blocking Programs on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, uac, limited-access

I am using Windows XP SP3 and I am having problem controlling `.exe` on my computer. Is there a way to me to control the programs I would allow my the users of my computer and if the program isn't in the list, would prompt for the administrator account to continue?

I have seen a number of suggestion over the Internet but all of the require a series of steps. Is there an easy way for me to idealize this concept (like the use of User Account Control, etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific on which solutions you've already looked at. Otherwise, you may get an answer you implicitly didn't want.

Comment: Sorry for the verbose question. I have edited the question. Hope to get answers soon.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Access Control Lists (ACLs) by means of tools such as `cacls`, `xcacls` and the security tab in the file/folder properties in Explorer to do one of the following:

1. explicitly deny the `Execute` access to the `limited access` account on anything but the files it is allowed to run - since `Deny` takes precedence, this is the easiest way.
2. fix the permissions and only grant the `administrator` the `Execute` access to everything and only `limited access` the `Execute` access to the files it is supposed to be able to execute.

And yes, it's as simple as that. All the tools are aboard already.

Most other solutions will only execute known programs but without regard to the user trying to execute them. Please note that you can also use Group Policies, but they are less reliable.

---

Since you edited your question and changed the meaning a bit, let me suggest [SuRun](http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/#8). There are English resources available and the GUI of it is pretty intuitive.